# Recursion with power of

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to make a program which takes an input x, then puts it to the power of (x-1) and adds it to (x-1)^(x-2), etc, etc. **Using recursion.**

ex: x = 3: 3^2 + 2^1 + 1^0 = **12**

This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int foo(int x) {

    if (x = 0){
        return 0;
    }

    if (x > 0){
        return (pow(x, (x - 1)) + foo(x - 1));
    }
}

int main(){
    int result = foo(3);
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
```

}

I am just wondering what the problem is because I have been trying to figure out why I keep getting the output as
-858993460

Comment: You are assigning `x=0` instead of comparing `x` to zero (`x==0`)

Comment: `if (x = 0){ return 0; }` <-- if this is your real code, you should be getting `0` every time.

Comment: sorry that was a typo it should have been x=3!!

Comment: @Blorgbeard: no, the value of the assignment is 0, which evaluates as `false` condition, so that branch isn't taken, and the function never returns anything. Hence the indeterminate value.

Comment: 3^2 + 2^1 + 1^0 = 9 ? shouldn't be 9 + 2 + 1 = 12?

Comment: Also, you do not cover all of the possibilities in your function. (Even with the correct `x==0`, there are values of x which will not trigger a return statement in your code). This means that when the function exist, you get whatever is in the return register (usually the `eax` or `rax` register on an x86 or x64 machine respectively).

Comment: @callyalater this is a interesting case. when if (x=0) was put, compiler didn't report any error. Correct one shall be if(x <= 0)

Comment: Most compilers will warning you when you do something boneheaded like `if (x=0)` instead of `if (x==0)`. Did you disable (or ignore) the warnings?

Comment: There was a warning, but not error. In c# it would be an error.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf oops, I see. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the `pow` function wants [floating point parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow), so you are making the compiler secretly convert your integer parameters to floating point before calling the `pow` function.

Answer (score 1):

you have multiple problems with your code...
First....

```
if (x = 0){
        return 0;
    }
```

that `if` block will never be executed, as `x` will always be assigned to `0` which results to `false`. change that to

```
if (x == 0){
        return 0;
    }
```

Secondly, there is a code path that returns undefined behaviour because the first `if` block is never executed after assigning it to `0`.

```
int foo(int x) {

    if (x = 0){
        return 0;
    }

    if (x > 0){
        return (pow(x, (x - 1)) + foo(x - 1));
    }

    //WHERE is your default return???
}
```

Here is a fixed up version...

```
int foo(int x) {

    if (x < 1)
        return 0;
    return (pow(x, (x - 1)) + foo(x - 1));
}
```

---

BTW, when `x == 3`, the answer is `12`; ---> `3^2 + 2^1 + 1^0` = `12`.

Comment: Another possibility is to require `foo` to take an `unsigned int` or `uint` as a parameter to help with conceptual consistency.

Comment: Well explained! All programmers shall have OCD :D

Comment: @callyalater, true... But `std::pow` has no overloads for `unsigned` types.... All its arguments are promoted to floating point types which have no notion of `unsignedness` ...Nontheless, the OP could easily code up an efficient `pow` for his use, then, he can use `unsigned` for the "conceptual consistency"

Comment: That is true. I was thinking of `uint` for conceptual consistency. (It doesn't make sense to put a negative number into the function, so using a `uint` tells the caller how it should be used.) My programming design class kinda ruined me in this regard.

Comment: "so using a uint tells the caller how it should be used" True. +1 on that!

Comment: @RolandIllig I think he mistyped. The OP showed that the base is constantly decreasing as is the exponent. I submitted an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Dude !

```
if (x = 0){
    return 0;
}
```

should be

```
if (x <= 0){
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int foo(int x) {

    if (x <= 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return (pow(x, (x - 1)) + foo(x - 1));
    }
}

int main()
{
    int result = foo(3);
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```